# How do I to create root user in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am not able to access my root account on phpmyadmin.  I have my config.inc.php file set like this:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'admin24';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';
```

When I try to login the root user on phpmyadmin, I get this error:

```
 mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

And when I try to access the mysql terminal with the root user using this command:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

and after entering my password, I get this error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Check authentication plugin used.

Answer (score 0):

1st step: remove password in config.inc.php file like

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
```

2nd: go to localhost/phpmyadmin and log in without a password.
3rd: go to the user account tab and set a password (123) to 'root' user.
4th: this time fill your password into config.inc.php file

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '123';
```

5th: now login with a password to phpmyadmin.